# How to check what is inside an arcore image database?

Tags: android, arcore

I don't see any options for checking which images (and their sizes) are in a pre-built arcore image database. I checked the arcoreimg tool and the AugmentedImageDatabase API. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: [It looks like there is no actual images stored in AugmentedImageDatabase](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images) Cite google: ARCore can store feature point information for up to 1,000 reference images per image database. The database stores a compressed representation of the reference images. Each image occupies ~6KB. | So it looks like there is only feature points in database.

Comment: That's interesting. However I wasn't really interested in getting the image data. I just want a list of what's inside, sort of like the "input_image_list" that you pass to build-db.